# How to change QWS_SIZE in qt application?

Tags: qt, qtembedded

We usually export qt embedded environment variables like this:

```
export QWS_DISPLAY=[:]...[:]
export QWS_SIZE=800*600
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$QTDIR/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Now I hope QWS_SIZE will be changed in my application .In other words, I hope Qt application can control the framebuffer size . Can QWSServer::Geometry do it ? I failed .
Thanks for any replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QWSServer widgets are not like QWidgets. One major philosophical difference is that you don't control them nearly as much. They are *supplied* to your application and are controlled by the *environment*.

So the answer to your question is: no. The application doesn't control the framebuffer size, the *device* does.